# How can I add up the sequence?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 2)
        return 2;
    else
        return f(n - 3) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 1);
}

int sum(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return f(0);
    else
        return f(x) + sum(x - 1) + sum(x-2);
}

int main() {
    int input;
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    printf("%d", sum(input));
}
```

Fn is a sequence defined as
f0 = 0, f1 = 1, f2 = 2, f3 = f2 + f1 + f0, fn = fn-3 + fn-2 + fn-1

sum() is defined as
sum(n) = (f0) + (f0+f1) + (f0 + f1 + f2) + .... + (f0 + f1 + ... + fn)

The output of the input n-th number should be like this
input / output = 0/0, 1/1, 2/4, 4/22

I have figured out that sum() can be written as
f(0)x5 + f(1)x4 + f(2)x3 + f(3)x2 + f(4)x1, if n is 4.
is there a way I can do this by recursion?

Comment: You just want to sum up the entire sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a recursive helper fuction for `sum()` could solve the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int n) {
    if (n < 3)
        return n;

    return f(n - 3) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 1);
}

int sum_recursive(int n, int x) {
    if (x == 1)
        return f(n);

    return f(n) * x + sum_recursive(n + 1, x - 1);
}

int sum(int x) {
    return sum_recursive(0, x + 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", sum(atoi(argv[1])));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> ./a.out 0
0
> ./a.out 1
1
> ./a.out 2
4
> ./a.out 3
10
> ./a.out 4
22
>
```